# How do I import this API from github into my project?

Tags: java, eclipse, github

I was trying to import [this](https://github.com/a64adam/ulti) github project into my eclipse project and use the API in my project, but I'm not sure how to do so. I apologize if it seems that I haven't researched this, but since I don't know what to refer to the github project as, I don't know how to research this myself.

Comment: Try learning about egit http://www.eclipse.org/egit/

Comment: @BalwinderSingh I did import the project with EGit, I just don't really know how to start using the API as documented in the readme, sorry for being unclear. [This](https://i.imgur.com/QGAf1sn.png?1) is what is looks like

Comment: If you look into their github page then you can find that they also provide downloadable jars. Include those jars in your project classpath and the use them as mentioned in the usage section of their github page

Comment: It is quite easy without secondary libraries or tools. Just download their `jar` file (under releases). After that go to your Eclipse and search the library section. There you can add libraries to eclipse by adding `jar` files (you can also add documentation and source files). After that you hit your project, properties, libraries and enable this library for this project. Now it will be in the build path of the project and you can use it. Surely you'll find a more detailed description searching "*eclipse import jar as library*".

Comment: It lists Maven and Gradle dependency declarations right there in the README, and you should very much learn to use at least one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a maven project. Maven is a library management tool that can help you to manage dependencies and help you compile and package.
In the readme page, they also provide maven dependency.